# Bug? When selecting a date range within product report, an order report is generated instead

Tags: cartthrob

Within the CartThrob Order Manager, on the product report tab, under the the initial report, there is an option to choose a date range. When I select a date range and generated the report, an order report is generated instead.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have been in contact with MightyBigRobot, and they confirmed that this is a bug and they are working on it.

As a temporary workaround I built a SQL query and embedded it into a custom report template. that looks like this:

```
<h1>Product Totals for the Past 7 Days</h1>


<table class="mainTable padTable">
<tr>
    <td></td>
<td>Product</td>
<td>Total Sold</td>
<td>Current Inventory</td>
<td>Unit</td>
<td>Need</td>
</tr>


{exp:query sql="
SELECT SUM(`exp_cartthrob_order_items`.`quantity`) AS total_quantity, `exp_cartthrob_order_items`.*,  exp_channel_titles.entry_date, FROM_UNIXTIME(exp_channel_titles.entry_date) AS MYDATE, exp_channel_titles.status,
exp_channel_data.entry_id as product_id, exp_channel_data.field_id_72 AS unit, exp_channel_data.field_id_78 AS unit_numerical, exp_channel_data.field_id_7 AS inventory,
(SUM(`exp_cartthrob_order_items`.`quantity`)* exp_channel_data.field_id_78) as need
FROM (`exp_cartthrob_order_items`, `exp_channel_titles` AS ct, `exp_channel_data`)
JOIN `exp_channel_titles` ON `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `exp_cartthrob_order_items`.`order_id`
WHERE ct.entry_id = exp_cartthrob_order_items.entry_id
AND exp_channel_titles.entry_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND exp_channel_titles.entry_date  < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND `exp_channel_titles`.`status` =  'open'
AND exp_channel_data.entry_id = exp_cartthrob_order_items.`entry_id`
GROUP BY `exp_cartthrob_order_items`.`entry_id`, `exp_cartthrob_order_items`.`price`
ORDER BY `total_quantity` DESC
"}


<tr>
<td>{count}</td>
<td>{title}   {exp:basee64:decode}{extra}{/exp:basee64:decode}   </td>
<td>{total_quantity} </td>
<td>{inventory}</td>
<td>{if unit=="kg"}{unit_numerical}/{/if}{unit}</td>
<td>{need} {if unit=="kg"}kg{/if}</td>
</tr>
{/exp:query}
```